# Calling a function in @parallel results in huge memory allocations

Tags: debugging, memory, memory-management, julia

I have created a minimum working example of my previous question ([Julia allocates huge amount of memory for unknown reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296176/julia-allocates-huge-amount-of-memory-for-unknown-reason)), isolating the problem.  This can be directly tested in the REPL.  Consider the code:

```
function test1(n)
    s = zero(Float64)
    for i = 1:10^n
        s += sqrt(rand()^2 + rand()^2 + rand()^2)
    end
    return s
end
```

--

```
function test2(n)
    @parallel (+) for i = 1:10^n
        sqrt(rand()^2 + rand()^2 +rand()^2)
    end
end
```

--

```
function test3(n)
    function add(one, two, three)
        one + two + three
    end

    @parallel (+) for i = 1:10^n
        sqrt(add(rand()^2, rand()^2, rand()^2))
    end
end
```

Then, I test the code:

```
@time test1(8);
@time test1(8);

@time test2(8);
@time test2(8);

@time test3(8);
@time test3(8);
```

And here is the output:

```
elapsed time: 1.017241708 seconds (183868 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 1.033503964 seconds (96 bytes allocated)

elapsed time: 1.214897591 seconds (3682220 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 1.020521156 seconds (2104 bytes allocated)

elapsed time: 15.23876415 seconds (9600679268 bytes allocated, 26.69% gc time)
elapsed time: 15.418865707 seconds (9600002736 bytes allocated, 26.19% gc time)
```

Can someone explain:

- Why does the first run of each function allocate so much memory?
- Why is the memory allocated in `test2(8)` higher than `test1(8)`?  They do the same thing.
- Most importantly, what the heck is going on with `test3(8)`?  It's allocating HUGE amounts of memory.

**EDIT:**

```
Julia Version 0.3.1
Commit c03f413* (2014-09-21 21:30 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Darwin (x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

Comment: This doesn't happen for me.  What does `versioninfo()` say?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Edited to add Julia version

Answer (score 2):

In the first run of each function, the allocation is due to compilation: remember that much of julia's JIT compiler is written in julia, and so any memory that gets consumed in the course of compilation (mostly, type analysis) gets included. Once the function has been compiled, this allocation disappears.

For me, both test2 and test3 allocate around 50K bytes on the 2nd runs (with `julia -p 2`).

Finally, the reason the parallel versions allocate some extra memory has to do with how `@parallel` works. It basically has to create a "thunk" out of your function and pass it to other processes. This thunk is not precompiled, because it might depend on variables that you pass in as arguments.

Comment: How long does test3 take to run for you, and what version of Julia are you using?  I tried running it on version 3.2 on a Linux machine instead and I still got 9600711508 bytes allocated, 24.90 seconds (much longer than test1 and test2)

Comment: On my old and slow laptop with `Julia Version 0.4.0-dev+2043` and `addprocs(2)`, I get the following: (function call, approximate time (secs), bytes allocated) -> [(`test1(8)`, 9.8, 72), (`test2(8)`, 4.9, ~ 32k), (`test3(8)`, 39, ~ 34k)]

Comment: @Nick Try your code on [JuliaBox](https://juliabox.org/).  No giant allocations seen there either.  It's much faster than my laptop.

Comment: I got 9600003104 bytes allocated on JuliaBox.  9 GB?  Only run it with one processor.